# How to define routes in more than one location?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to define routes in various parts of a website.

Example, if I wanted to break functionality of my website out into modules, and each module would define the routes it needs.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using ASP.NET MVC's built-in **Areas**.

An "Area" is essentially your module, and Areas allow you to register routes for each specific area.

If you've not used them before there is an MSDN walkthrough here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx

Essentially, you have a directory for each area, which contains all your area-specific controllers and views, and in the route of that directory you place a file that registers the routes for that particular area like so:

```
public class MyAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
 {
     public override string AreaName
     {
         get { return "My Area"; }
     }

     public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
     {
         context.MapRoute(
             "news-articles",
             "my-area/articles/after/{date}",
             new {controller = "MyAreaArticles", action = "After"}
             );

         // And so on ...
     }
}
```

In global.asax.cs you need to register all these extra areas, along with your other primary routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Products",
        "products/show/{name}",
            new {controller = "Products", action = "Show", name = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );

    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 - It took me 5 minutes to find a suitable link to post here about Areas, by then you beat me to it... :) Just for extra info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243158/how-to-configure-areas-in-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: @AJC Thanks. I feel guilty now, for stealing your thunder! But yes, I know what you mean. There's not an "official" link for Areas, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a `DefineRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` method in each module, then call them all in Global.asax.cs.

Comment: and if to make it dynamic you can use reflection to scan the folders?

Comment: You can loop through `typeof(MyType).Assembly.GetTypes()` and find all types that implement an `IModuleInitializer` interface, or something like that.