# MVC3 HTML ActionLink not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a DashBoardController.cs here i have this code

```
public class DashBoardController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /DashBoard/

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /New Project/

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult NewProject()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /File Upload/

        public ActionResult UploadFile()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            // Verify that the user selected a file
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

    }
```

I have another masterlayout file here i have this code

```
<div id="LeftColumn" class="ui_style_floatLeft">
            <div id="menuWrapper">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menuDashBoard">@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard","Index")</li>
                    <li class="menuProject"><a href="#">Project</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("New Project","NewProject")</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                   
                    <li class="menuAccount"><a href="#">Account</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Change Password", "ChangePassword", "Account")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                  
                </ul>               
             </div>
        </div>
```

But If i goto `Change Password` action link then other link (`New Project`, `Dashboard`) not working. i try `@Url.Action` into a herf attr but not working :(

what should i do now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- LinkText: "Dashboard"
- ActionName: "index"
- ControllerName: "dashboard"

  @Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "index", "dashboard")

If you are using [areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243158/how-to-configure-areas-in-asp-net-mvc3) to group controllers into different areas you would need.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "index", "dashboard", new { area = "YourAreaName"})
```

Comment: I am new in MVC3. What `Area` actually did ? Can you give me a link where i can know about `Area` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the controller name in your [action link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505070.aspx):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard","Index","DashBoard")
```

If you leave out the `controllerName`, then the links will be constructed with the *current controller*. Since you navigated to the `AccountController`, the link that was supposed to point to the `DashboardController` broke.

In shared areas (like navigation), you'll usually want to include the controller reference.

Comment: Yes man but it only work for this `@Html.ActionLink("New Project","NewProject","Project")` but `@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard","Index","DashBoard")` not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505070.aspx) overload

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Project","NewProject","DashBoard")
```

this is the format

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName
)
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, but it work for only NewProject link but not for DashBoard Index :(

Comment: Did you use the same overload for the link for Index action ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look closely, I think you did not put the controller for the `"NewProject"` and `"Index"` methods

try replacing

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Project","NewProject")
```

for

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Project","NewProject", "DashBoard")
```

and

```
@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard","Index")
```

for

```
@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard","Index", "DashBoard")
```