# mvc 4 web api for multiple applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

My mvc 4 application exposes an API layer for 3 different child applications. I am using a single api controller for all the three child apps. All these three apps uses the parent app DB.

I would like to know if i am doing anything wrong with this. Also, as the app develops, the api controller is becoming heavy. Is there any good way by which i can manage the child app in the parent app project?.

Comment: Can you provide more context on your question? It's ok to have a single entry point for your API, but I would divide the methods on different controllers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of **Areas** to manage your child apps in the parent one. Please follow steps answered in the question below to create areas in your project

[How to Configure Areas in ASP.NET MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243158/how-to-configure-areas-in-asp-net-mvc3)

For handling Api requests to areas, you need to have two routes in the area registration.

```
  public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Area_Name_Api",
            routeTemplate: "Area_Name/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        context.MapRoute(
            "Area_Name_default",
            "Area_Name/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

The first route is for reaching api controller in the area and second one for regular ones.

http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-mvc-4-rc-getting-webapi-and-areas-to-play-nicely/

The above link explains more on this.

By this way you can separate your child apps and organize your functions, models views(if any) in the parent project.

Answer (score 4):

You can handle the child apps under different web api controllers.